# Grupo de Rutas Resource no devuelve vista index Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

Hola t0dos como estan? tengo el siguiente problema bien raro: tengo definida la siguiente ruta del tipo resource:

```
Route::resource('productos/portafolio', ImagenesProductosController::class)->names('crud.productos.imagenes');
```

pero estoy teniendo el problema que no me funciona el metodo index en particular, en el metodo solamente devuelvo una vista, entonces si ingreso via navegador asi:

http://localhost:8000/productos/portafolio/index solo me devuelve la pantalla en blanco (sin errores ni nada) en vambio si ingreso al metodo create: http://localhost:8000/productos/portafolio/create me devuelve la vista de creacion sin problemas...

He probado vaciando cache, limpiando y cacheando rutas pero aun asi nada...

Alguien ha pasado por lo mismo?

Comment: Probaste sin el index del final? Sólo `http://localhost:8000/productos/portafolio`

Comment: Si, y me devuelve al método show ya que me devuelve esa vista

Comment: Mmm... Para que acceda al método show deberías pasarle una id como parámetro `http://localhost:8000/productos/portafolio/1`. Mejor muestra lo que tienes en el controlador y el resultado de `php artisan router:list` para esa ruta. También las vistas que devuelven index y show